# How do I get the type of (sequence .) . fmap?

Tags: haskell, type-systems

I try to understand how Haskell type inference and type system works. Now I'm studying the case of `(sequence .) . fmap`. I get types of `(sequence .)` and `(. fmap)` as haskell does:

```
(.)      ::                             (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
fmap     :: Functor f                => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a)  -> m (t a)

-- Type for . fmap:
a ~ (a -> b)
b ~ (f a -> f b)
. fmap              :: ((f a -> f b) -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> c)

-- Type for sequence:
b ~ t (m a1)
c ~ m (t a2)
sequence .          :: (a1 -> t (m a2)) -> (a1 -> m (t a2))
```

But then I can't get the type of `(sequence .) . fmap`. I tryed following steps and then stucked:

```
(sequence .) . fmap - ?

f a ~ a1
f b ~ t (m a2)
b ~ m a2
c ~ (a1 -> m (t a2))
(sequence .) . fmap :: (a -> m a2) -> (a1 -> m (t a2))
```

The type I've got differs from the one haskell give.

**UPD** Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem, I've got some progress, but then stucked again...

```
(.)    ::              (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(fmap) :: Functor f => (z -> u) -> f z -> f u
sequence .          :: (a1 -> t (m a2)) -> (a1 -> m (t a2))

b ~ (a1 -> t (m a2))
c ~ (a1 -> m (t a2))
a ~ (z -> u)
(sequence .) . fmap :: ((a1 -> t (m a2)) -> (a1 -> m (t a2))) ->
                       ((z -> u) -> (a1 -> t (m a2))) ->
                       ((z -> u) -> (a1 -> m (t a2))
```

Comment: Note that the function here is actually `(.) ((.) sequence) fmap`, so the `.` applies first on the `sequence`, not on the `fmap`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks! Seems I did substitution wrong :-(

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can I substitute `t (m a2) ~ ((a -> b) -> c)`?

Comment: You can get a second equation on `b` from the type of `fmap` . Then the two equations beginning `b ~` will let you eliminate some of the other variables.

Comment: Side note: with rare exceptions, `sequenceA` has supplanted `sequence`. The exceptions tend to involve `Traversable` containers represented as effectful streams.

Comment: By the way, you can take a bit of a short cut to figuring this one out. `(sequence .) . fmap = \f -> (sequence .) (fmap f) = \f -> sequence . fmap f = mapM f`, and we know that `mapM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)`. If you used `sequenceA` instead, you'd end up with `traverse` instead, weakening the `Monad` constraint to an `Applicative` one. Even if you don't want to take that shortcut, transforming to the lambda form I showed will very likely help you work out the type more directly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep our type variables all distinct.

```
(.)      ::                             (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
fmap     :: Functor f                => (u -> v) -> f u -> f v
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m x)  -> m (t x)
```

We have two uses of the function `.`. I will use `a1` and the like for the first one, and `a2` and the like for the second one.

In `(sequence .)`, we have `(b1 -> c1) = (t (m x)  -> m (t x))`, so `b1 = t (m x)` and `c1 = m (t x)`. Using substitution, `.` is specialized to `(t (m x) -> m (t x)) -> (a1 -> t (m x)) -> a1 -> m (t x)`, and after being applied to `sequence`, we have a term of type `(a1 -> t (m x)) -> a1 -> m (t x)`.

Now we can look at the second `.`, `(sequence .) . fmap`. Here, we have `(b2 -> c2) = (a1 -> t (m x)) -> a1 -> m (t x)`, and `(a2 -> b2) = (u -> v) -> f u -> f v`.

This means that:

```
b2 = a1 -> t (m x)
c2 = a1 -> m (t x)
a2 = (u -> v)
b2 = f u -> f v
```

Notice that we have `b2` up there twice, which means that `a1 = f u` and `t (m x) = f v`, so we can also derive that `f = t`, `v = m x`.

Now that we know all of those types, we know that the second `.` is specialized to

```
((t u -> t (m x)) -> (t u -> m (t x)) 
  -> ((u -> m x) -> (t u -> t (m x))) 
  -> (u -> m x) 
  -> (t u -> m (t x))
```

But we've already applied both of `.`'s arguments, so the whole expression's type is `(u -> m x) -> (t u -> m (t x))`.

And from there, it's just variable renaming, constraints, and parenthesis away from what ghci gives me.

```
> :t (sequence .) . fmap
(sequence .) . fmap
  :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a1 -> m a) -> t a1 -> m (t a)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's late but still, I would like to answer.

These were the steps I took to understand `.).`

Actually It's not type inference that need, we Need to understand Substitution steps and type inference will just fallout.

as pointed in one comment, supposed substation is incorrect.

**Substation steps for (sequence .) . fmap**

1. `sequence .` -- `(.)` composition operator takes `sequence` as left argument
2. `(sequence .) .` -- outer `(.)` takes `(sequence .)` as left argument
3. `(sequence .) . fmap` -- outer `(.)` takes `fmap` as right argument

**Why we even need `.).` in first place**

lets take a simple example
what if I want to compose 2 functions first with two arguments and second with one

here I have taken simple example

```
i' :: Int -> Int -> String
i' x = show . (x +)
```

**Substitution order**

1. `show .` -- `(.)` takes `show` as left argument
2. `x +` -- `(+)` takes `x` as left argument
3. `show . (x +)` -- `(.)` takes `(x +)` as right argument

**What if we like to make is point free ?**

here it is

```
i :: Int -> Int -> String
i = (show .) . (+)
```

**Substitution order**

1. `show .` -- `(.)` takes `show` as left argument
2. `(show .) .` -- outer `(.)` takes `(show .)` as left argument
3. `(show .) . (+)` -- `(.)` takes `(x)` as right argument

***We can even create an operator for it***

```
(.~.) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> c
f .~. g = (f .) . g -- wish I could name it (..)
```

and use it like this

```
f :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a1 -> m a) -> t a1 -> m (t a)
f = sequence .~. fmap
```

So `.).` is nothing but `(f .)` taking `. g` in right argument where g will take 2 argument.

BTW nothing is stopping us from

```
jj ::(Show b)=> (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> String
jj = (((show .) . ) . someFunctionWithThreeArguments
```